# Convex Optimization problem with sum of absolute value constraints

Tags: constrained-optimization, quadratic-programming

How to solve the optimization problem written below?

$$\begin{align}
&\operatorname{argmax}\limits_{a}\; a^T b - \frac{1}{2}  a^T X a\\
&\text{subject to } \sum_i |a_i|=4,\;  \sum_i a_i = 0
\end{align}$$

where $a$, $b$ are $n$-vectors and $X$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Also, $b$ and $X$ are constants.

My main issue is about the absolute values. Without absolute values, there is actually an analytic solution. I guess with absolute values, I have to use iterative approach such as quadratic programming but still not sure how to express the problem to call relevant optimization procedures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, your problem isn't a convex optimization problem because the constraint $\Sigma_{i} | a_{i}|=4$ describes a non-convex feasible region.  If you could change this to $\Sigma_{i} | a_{i} | \leq 4$, you'd have a convex constraint.

If the constraint were $\Sigma_{i} | a_{i} | \leq 4$, then you can introduce auxiliary variables $t_{i}$, and add the constraints

$\Sigma_{i} t_{i} \leq 4$

$t_{i} \geq a_{i}$  for all $i$

$t_{i} \geq -a_{i}$ for all $i$

This is a standard reformulation technique in convex optimization.

Another issue with your original problem statement is that $X$ must be positive semidefinite to ensure concavity of the objective function.

Assuming that $X$ is positive semidefinite, you've now got a linear constrained convex quadratic programming problem which is solvable by lots of solvers.

Comment: I see your point. Let's say the constraint is changed to Σi|ai|≤4, how then it should be solved?

Comment: see my expanded answer.

Comment: what if you had another constraint sum(abs(a))>=2?

Comment: That set described by $\sum | a_{i} | \geq 2$ isn't a convex set, and this your problem couldn't be formulated as a convex optimization problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks for the answer. Out of interest, do you have a text book reference for this?

Comment: This is discussed in Vandenberghe and Boyd's textbook on Convex Optimization among others.